# Can we customize ABNewPersonController in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, customization, abaddressbook

How can we customize the  AB new Person controller in ABAddressBook Framework?
 I want to change text of navigation bar of AB new Person controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes ...you can change the text of navigation bar of ABNewPersonViewController...*

```
ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
picker.displayedPerson = person;
picker.navigationItem.title=@"YOUR TITLE";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks prasanna ,but i want more customization like i want to stop to show full size of contact image means i don't want to allow tap on image view. Is it possible ?

Comment: I found a property "allowsEditing" for ABPersonViewController class have a look of it..... that what it does......

Comment: it's okay but more than navigation bar title can't be modified.

Comment: Yes... accept changing tint color (including view also)and navigation title , you can not modify the native ABPersonViewController